# Select a field from table that contains parenthesis

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a fieldname with parenthesis () and be able to call it with a query. For example I have a field name called...

```
 EnoughMoney(0)

 Select EnoughMoney(0) from tbl1
```

When I select it in SSMS i get the following error....

> 'EnoughMoney' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: In SQL Server you can escape column names (and other names as well) by enclosing them into square brackets: `select [EnoughMoney(0)] from tbl1`

Comment: All the more reason not to have spaces or special characters in column names. If 0 is really important, i'd suggest `EnoughMoney_0` or `EnoughMoney0`

Comment: @stefano - if you want to post as answer i'll accept it. thanks

Comment: @scsimon - i don't actually want to use the ()'s except I have to. I reference the field in my application and I had to save it in an array

Comment: You might want to put more thought into your application.  If your current approach is compelling you to have an unwise database design, maybe there are better approaches available.

Comment: @DanBracuk - thanks - yes I am likely to consider other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you can escape names (of columns or of anything else) in SQL Server is by enclosing them in square brackets. Your query will work if you write it like

```
select [EnoughMoney(0)] from tbl1
```

As correctly stated by others, it's usually a good practice to avoid spaces and special characters in database objects' names, unless you are forced to, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select [EnoughMoney(0)] from tbl1`